# difference between column of dates and a fixed date

Tags: r

```
shoot <- read.csv('shoot.csv')
finish <- as.Date(shoot$`Year of Incorporation`, format="%mm/%dd/%yyyy")
start <- 12/31/2016
date_diff <- as.data.frame(finish-start)
```

What changes should be done in this to get output as number of dates between data set and `31/12/2016`??

Comment: `as.Date(...., format = '%m/%d/%Y)`

Comment: In the `lubridate` package, you can use `difftime` function.

Comment: i don't know why it's still not getting executed can u provide the complete steps?